# javascript number of images

Tags: javascript

I have a small html file for personal use, with no css or php or web server. I have a folder 'imgs' (in the same folder as the .html) that contains images called image0.png, image1.png, image2.png... (all in sequence, until there is none). How could I make a javascript function that returns the number of images in that folder ?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to immediately get the number of image files using client-side JavaScript, the best you could do is to try retrieving the images one by one until, you get a 404 error.

You can use the `onerror` method of an img element to detect when a requested image doesn't exist - this method will be called if you request an image that isn't there.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images) might be useful, it contains some example code which you could use.

Comment: 404 error ? I said no web server, no http request, no nothing. The setup could hardly be simpler, I'm the client and the server (well, not even the server actually, there's just a client). I think the idea is indeed to try to get the images until it fails, but I don't know how to do that. What would the code look like ?

Comment: Your browser will still behave as though it got a 404 error, even without a web server.

Comment: Really? That's amazing! So maybe it's the way to go, what would the function be like then ?

Comment: The onerror handler will still work even for local files (no web server)

Comment: ok thanks, I'll accept the other answer because there is code that explains how to do it, but you had the same idea so I plusOned you.

Answer (score 2):

The general strategy would be to load each file as an image, in order, until a request failed, firing an `onerror` callback. Each subsequent image fetch is fired as the `onload` handler of the previous image.

```
// takes a callback that expects a single argument
function getImageCount(callback) {
    imageCounter(0);

    // pseduo-recursive function nested in the closure of the outer function
    // (nested so `callback` is always accessible without constantly passing it)
    function imageCounter(i) {
        var img = new Image();

        // if this failed, so the final image was the previous one
        img.onerror = function() { callback(i); }
        // if this succeeded, try the next one
        img.onload = function() { imageCounter(i + 1); }

        img.src = "image"+i+".png";
    }
}

// actually run it, with callback function that gets the count
getImageCount(function(count) {
    alert("There are " + count + "images.");
});
```

Due to restrictive same-origin policy for `file:` URLs, this won't work on Chrome without the `--allow-file-access-from-files` command line flag, and it will only work in Firefox if the images are being fetched from the same directory or a subdirectory of the current page.

Comment: Thanks, that seems the way to go. Is there a way to modify it to make a simple function 'reallyGetCount()' that just returns an integer that is the count of images ? I would like to wrap your code into a black box, because I'm not too familiar with callbacks.

Comment: Unfortunately, in JavaScript, callbacks *are* a legitimate part of function black boxes. There's no way to load images synchronously, so there's no way to synchronously return a result from a function that depends on image loads. Callbacks are a bit difficult to use effectively at first, but they are absolutely necessary for virtually all advanced browser functionality and JS libraries.

Comment: but could I not make yet another function that uses this callback stuff, and actually returns the value I'm interested in ?!

Comment: No, you cannot. This is how it would work if you tried: 1) the black box function (BBF) starts, 2) BBF registers listener functions on image `onload` and `onerror`, 3) BBF terminates [with no return value], 4) `onload`/`onsuccess` listener functions fire.  The obvious intuition is to delay termination of the BBF until after a callback fires (i.e., delay step 3 until step 4 completes).  However, this is **not possible** because JS is single-threaded: the BBF needs to complete and return before any other functions (including the listener functions) can run. Thus, step 4 *must* come after step 3.

Comment: Instead of the alert, can I do n=count, where n is a global variable ?

Comment: Certainly, you can do anything you want in the callback. Just remember that the global `n` won't be set until the callback completes, so `getImageCount(function(count){ n=count; }); alert(n); doStuff(n);` will alert undefined (since the `alert` and `doStuff` run before the callback), but `getImageCount(function(count){ n=count;  alert(n); doStuff(n); });` will succeed (since the `alert` and `doStuff` are in the callback).

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't understand how it is that I can use your code into mine. I just wanted a function to tell me how many images there are in my folder... does that mean I have to place my whole code into your callback function for it to work? I don't understand why in the first case, you say the alert runs before the callback. What calls the callback, if not the getImageCount(function(count){ n=count; }); ?!

Comment: *"Does that mean I have to place my whole code into your function for it to work?"* -- Yes, correct, that is exactly what you need to do. You can move your code into a function and provide that function as the callback, if you want.  Regarding why the alert runs first: `getImageCount` does not run the callback; instead, it *registers the callback for later execution* by providing it as the `onerror` handler of the image. The callback can only run after the current execution flow has terminated. Callbacks cannot interrupt the execution flow; they only run when the JS thread has gone idle.

Comment: I tried both (inside and outside of the callback, none worked). Here is my code (line 49-52): http://pastebin.com/HbALuzGE